# Group By Statement Results in Too Many Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 6 product lines that I am trying to find throughput for. The equation for throughput is: `throughput = PoundsMade/ActualRunningTime`.

I know what `PoundsMade` is (there's 6 rows, because of the 6 product lines), via a simple `SELECT` statement. I calculated the `ActualRunningTime` using a different `SELECT` statement (again, 6 product lines results in 6 rows).

Note: I'm using these smaller `SELECT` statements, for now, so I can piece the problem together later.

So, when I combine everything and write a single select statement for Throughput, it looks like:

```
SELECT 
   (SUM(rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.PoundsMade)) / ((24 * 60 * 60) - 
      (SUM(cast(([Production Downtime].[End Time] - [Production Downtime].[Start Time]) as float))))
FROM 
    rpt_Line_Shift_Prod, [Production Downtime]
GROUP BY 
    rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber, [Production Downtime].[Line #];
```

This larger `SELECT` statement results in 36 rows. I only want 6 rows. I need a throughput value for each of the 6 product lines.

Questions:

1. Why is the above `SELECT` statement resulting in 36 rows?
2. How can I force it to only show 6 rows?

Comment: When you're doing a grouping, you will get any records that are unique.  So, if one of your time values is 1 second off from another group, you will get another row.  If you need to consolidate your rows so you have less, you will need to broaden your range.

Comment: Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style can lead to exactly what you see: a **cartesian product** since you forgot to add a **join condition** to your `WHERE` clause. Switch to the new SQL-92 JOIN syntax!

Comment: @marc_s:
I will try that. Thanks. I'm rather new to SQL. So, I apparently used the old-style join without realizing.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying a join column. This means SQL is returning every combination between the two tables. 6x6 = 36.

```
WHERE rpt_Line_Shift_Prod.LineNumber = [Production Downtime].[Line #]
```

Comment: Or, better yet, use an `INNER JOIN` instead of an implicit `CROSS JOIN` followed by your `WHERE`. It will give the same results, it will perform the same, but wins in readability.

Comment: @hvd is right. Especially since the comma style of join is deprecated, so people should move toward explicit joins.